# Python, How to stop tkinter variables from being garbage-collected?

Tags: python, tkinter, garbage-collection

I have a function that creates a tkinter window with many checkbutton widgets on it. Later, a button on another window saves the states of these checkbuttons. The function that does this is passed the reference to the window the checkbuttons are on, through which (by `.winfo_children()`) it gets the references to each checkbutton widget.

Even though all the checkbuttons on the window are created, set, and `get`'d identically, different ones throw an error each time the code is run: `_tkinter.TclError: can't read "PY_VAR0": no such variable`.

This leads me to believe that some of my `BooleanVar()` tkinter variables are being garbage-collected while I still need them. **How do I stop my tkinter variables from being garbage-collected?**

---

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69869082/python-tkinter-cant-get-value-of-checkbutton-as-child), but I would prefer a solution that stops the garbage-collection in the first place, as changing the structure of my functions would be difficult.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Like with any python object, you need to keep a permanent reference to them. Either you need to save them as an attribute of an object, or you need to make them a global variable.

You might also be seeing the problem if you create more than one instance of `Tk`, and create a variable in one root window but try to use it in another.